# Reading percentages with recfromtxt in python

Tags: python

I have a .txt file that looks like this:

```
0   0,0%    41,3%   22,1%   28,9%
1   0,0%    40,4%   27,4%   37,8%
2   0,0%    42,5%   30,1%   48,5%
```

the only way I managed to import it is like this:

```
d1  = np.recfromtxt(path+file, delimiter = '\t', usecols=(0,1,2,3,4), names= ["h","a","b","c","d"], dtype=(None,'U8','U8','U8','U8'))
```

which the following

```
[(0., '0,0%', '41,3%', '22,1%', '28,9%')
 (1., '0,0%', '40,4%', '27,4%', '37,8%')
 (2., '0,0%', '42,5%', '30,1%', '48,5%')]
```

To work with the data I then have to convert all my strings. I am sure I am misunderstanding something.  That is, I would like to get something like

```
[(0., 0,0, 41,3, 22,1, 28,9)
 (1., 0,0, 40,4, 27,4, 37,8)
 (2., 0,0, 42,5, 30,1, 48,5)]
```

If somebody could suggest an easier way and explain how it works I would be really grateful.

Comment: Could you add what you want your final `d1` to look like?

Comment: oh basically I just want the % numbers to converted to floats rather than strings.

Answer (score 0):

A rather longer workaround as I was not able to read the data using the function `recfromtxt` (As in, it gave me an error when I tried to read using the sample data):

```
fin = open("file.txt")
data = fin.readlines()
fin.close()

d = [i.strip().replace(",", ".").replace("%", "") for i in data]
d = [i.split() for i in d]
d = np.array(d)
d = d.astype('float64')
```

The output is as follows:

```
array([[ 0. ,  0. , 41.3, 22.1, 28.9],
       [ 1. ,  0. , 40.4, 27.4, 37.8],
       [ 2. ,  0. , 42.5, 30.1, 48.5]])
```